# how to replace a nth column with column separated string using sed/awk

Tags: text-processing, sed

Assume I a have string like:

```
xyz="123" ; acd="234" ; plk="1234" ; apl="3456" ; www="2342"
```

Now I want to replace `plk="123"` with `plk="789"` using sed by ignoring `;` and `""`.

OUTPUT:

```
xyz="123" ; acd="234" ; plk="789" ; apl="3456" ; www="2342
```

Please help me with this and let me know if we can use other commands.

Comment: What do you mean by " ignoring `;` and `""`"? Why are those relevant? Don't you just need to replace the string `plk="1234"` with `plk="789"`?

Comment: The text says "`plk="123"`" but the data shows "`plk="1234"`" -- if the *"4"* is a typo, it should be corrected.

Comment: Why is the last double quote missing? Do you want to strip the final double quote? Also, why is the output not `...plk="7894"...` with the `4` left remaining? If these are typos then please [edit] and provide ***accurate*** input and output examples.

Answer (score 0):

To replace `plk="1234"` with `plk="789"`, you can do:

```
$ sed 's/plk="1234"/plk="789"/g' file
xyz="123" ; acd="234" ; plk="789" ; apl="3456" ; www="2342"
```

However, that would also replace `notplk="1234"` with `plk="789"`. To avoid that, you can use `\<` so that it only matches on word boundaries:

```
$ sed 's/\<plk="1234"/plk="789"/g' file
xyz="123" ; acd="234" ; plk="789" ; apl="3456" ; www="2342"
```

I am not sure that the `\<` is 100% portable, so just in case, you can also do:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^| )plk="1234"/plk="789"/g' file
xyz="123" ; acd="234" ;plk="789" ; apl="3456" ; www="2342"
```

or use Perl instead:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\bplk="1234"/plk="789"/g' file
xyz="123" ; acd="234" ; plk="789" ; apl="3456" ; www="2342"
```

With all of the above commands, both `sed` and `perl`, you can add the `-i` flag to edit the original file in place.

---

The commands above will replace *all* occurrences of `plk="1234"` on every line of a file. You don't explain in your question, but in your title you mention the "nth column". I don't know how you define columns or what you mean by that, but in case you mean that you only want to make this replacement on the 3rd `;`-delimited column, you could try this (with GNU `awk`):

```
$ awk -F';'  'BEGIN{OFS=";"}{$3=gensub(/plk="1234"/,"plk=\"789\"",1,$3); }1' file
xyz="123" ; acd="234" ; plk="789" ; apl="3456" ; www="2342"
```

Comment: Hi terdon,

Thank you,

Regards sravya